# ibm App ID logout in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, logout, ibm-appid

I  integrate IBM APP ID in my project in local,after login succeed, when I try to log out use the following code as same as demo

```
app.get("/logout", function(req, res, next) {
    WebAppStrategy.logout(req);
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

nodejs show the request is successfully send but chrome console show the following error message:

- Failed to load [appid-auth-url] No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on
  the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore
  not allowed access.

appid-auth-url is provided by IBM, can't be set cors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present, Origin 'null' not allowed access - Passport-SteamStrategy, Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42845193/no-access-control-allow-origin-is-present-origin-null-not-allowed-access)

Comment: You need to allow CORS in your server.
Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18310394/no-access-control-allow-origin-node-apache-port-issue

Answer (score 0):

Check out the simple node.js web app that is implementing this functionality for a reference - https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-video-tutorials/tree/master/02a-simple-node-web-app.

You can also watch the App ID tutorial for protecting node.js applications - https://youtu.be/6roa1ZOvwtw